# Returning Data from the listview in the activity

Tags: android, listview

From the start activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MarkersActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, GoMarkerReturn);
```

call other activity in which there is CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter.
The listviewhas a picture, when clicked, to close the current activity and return the result to the starting activity

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        holder.imggo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            ...
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            int clickedPosition = (Integer)v.getTag();
            NewsItem newsItem = (NewsItem)listData.get(clickedPosition);                
            Long goID = newsItem.getID();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), StartActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("goID", goID);
            setResult(0, myIntent);
```

setResult(0, myIntent) dont work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
        holder.imggo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), StartActivity.class);
                myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                myIntent.putExtra("goID", goID);
                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```

and

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity{
...
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Long goID = intent.getLongExtra("goID", 0);
        if (goID > 0){
               ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`StartActivityForResult` and `setResult` is used to passed values between activities. Here in your case you need to call finish() in the second activity so that the second activity is destroyed and the first activity comes to foreground.

This is a good tutorial to learn how it functions. [DataTransfers](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intentdatatransfer)

Comment: finish() - The method finish() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Finish() is Activities method. You need to have Activity's reference in your Adapter code. Also, setResult() should use the same RESULT_CODE as used in the startAcvitiyforResult. Pls read the tutorial first and get a good understanding.

Comment: These methods work in extends Activity, but not running in extends BaseAdapter -> getView -> onClick